# вывод подробностей продукта под ссылкой в поиске google

Tags: seo, magento, google-search, feed

я нашёл много информации как правильно создавать feed для продуктов, и нашёл всего 1 атрибут который мне вроде как нужен, **product detail** но заветных атрибутов в поиске я так и не смог получить, вот пример чего я хочу добиться:

[image: 1]

у меня есть готовый фид где есть все атрибуты, сайт сделан на magento, чего мне не хватает? буду признателен любой помощи.

Answer (score 2):

Называется это Open Graph, стоит посмотреть что сайт-пример передаёт в `<og: ... >` и будет понятно что запихнуть в свой сайт.

**Open Graph tags**

- https://www.link-assistant.com/news/html-tags-for-seo.html

Comment: [https://i.imgur.com/2l5deN0.png](https://i.imgur.com/2l5deN0.png) вы уверены что это делается с помощью OG? на всех сайтах где я посмотрел подобные атрибуты, похоже на это, но нет намёка именно на отдельный OG - width и т.п

Comment: У нас на сайте уже есть og поэтому это не то что мне нужно, может есть ещё какие-то варианты?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/structured-data/product

Answer (score 0):

Для Гугл это могут быть расширенные результата поиска, которые создаются при использовании структурированных данных. Подробнее читайте руководство Гугл **[Расширенная поисковая оптимизация для продуктов](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/structured-data/product)**.